# RxJava's retryWhen unexpectedly keeps retrying forever

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java3, retrywhen

Can anyone …

1. explain why the following code keeps retrying indefinitely, once `retryWhen` is called?
2. correct the code to stop retrying when `Random.nextBoolean()`
   returns `true`?

I think there is a 50% chance that `retryWhen` is called because of `Random.nextBoolean()`. However, once it is called, it goes into an infinite loop.

```kotlin
import io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Observable
import kotlin.random.Random

fun main() {
    Observable
        .just(Unit)
        .flatMap {
            if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
                Observable.just(Unit)
            } else {
                Observable.error(Throwable())
            }.retryWhen {
                it.flatMap {
                    println("retryWhen")
                    Observable.just(Unit)
                }
            }
        }
        .subscribe()
}
```

Output:

```
retryWhen
retryWhen
retryWhen
⋮
(continued)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You've applied the `retryWhen` to the result of the execution of either branch of the if-statement.
2. Chain the `retryWhen` operator to the stream produced by `flatMap`:

e.g.

```
Observable
  .just(Unit)
  .flatMap {
    if(Random.nextBoolean()) {
      Observable.just(Unit)
    } else {
      Observable.error(Throwable())
    }
  }
  .retryWhen {
      it.flatMap {
        println("retryWhen")
        Observable.just(Unit)
      }
  }
  .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look the same [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46926208/rxjava-retrywhen-called-instantly/46927640#46927640)

Copied answer:

`retryWhen` calls the provided function when an `Observer` subscribes to it so you have a main sequence accompanied by a sequence that emits the `Throwable` the main sequence failed with. You should compose a logic onto the `Observable` you get in this `Function` so at the end, one `Throwable` will result in a value on the other end.

I think your expectation is:

```kotlin
Observable
            .just(Unit)
            .flatMap {
                if (Random.nextBoolean()) {
                    Observable.just(Unit)
                } else {
                    Observable.error(Throwable())
                }.retryWhen {
                    it.takeWhile {
                        Random.nextBoolean()
                    }
                        .doOnNext {
                            println("retryWhen")
                        }
                }
            }
            .subscribe()
```